# Using .bind (mootools) with onClick event

Tags: javascript, mootools, arguments, bind

I have the code (inside one object)

`onclick: this._addX.bind(this)`

and then inside another object

`onclick: this._addY.bind(this)`

Now, _addX() and _addY are nearly identical, except they both end up calling (on the click event) a function with different argument values, say _addX calls foo('x') and _addY calls foo('y').  So I tried:

`onclick: this._add.bind(this,'x')`  and 
`onclick: this._add.bind(this,'y')`  in the two objects.  And of course I changed _add to accept an argument.

At runtime, when _add is called, it does not see any incoming arguments!  I have fumbled around with different syntaxes but nothing works.  Any ideas?  The original syntax works fine (no arguments) but forces me to duplicate a large function with only one line different, which pains me.  Thanks in advance.

```
_add: function(which) {
    var me = this;
    var checkFull = function(abk) {
        if (abk.isFull) {
            alert("full");
        } else {
        alert(which);  // which is always undefined here!
        }
    };
    getAddressBook(checkFull); //checkFull is a fn called by getAddressBook
},
```

Comment: @Dave, Your code should work, but its not. Can you post the `_add` method declaration so we can troubleshoot it?

Comment: Ok, you are right. It looks fine. (I also fixed the indenting) The only two ways I know to define an event in MooTools is on the constructor (`{ events: { 'click': function(){ ... } }`) or by using `addEvent`. How exactly are you attaching the `onclick` function?

Comment: actually creating the button in YUI and using the onClick: attribute there.

            var btn_Add = new CO.GG.widget.Button({
                id: 'add',
                label: 'add X',
                onclick: this._add.bind(this,'x')
            });

I wonder if the 'which' (in the top post) is just not surviving from _add thru to the callback to checkFull()?

Comment: can't figure out how to format the comments...

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem, but to test just alert `which` right after the opening of the function. I am going to look at how YUI handles the onclick in the mean time. Also: Use backticks around your code pieces in the comments, and four space indents in the questions and answers.

Comment: thanks -- you have been helpful.  You are right - it is already undefined on entry to _add().  I have to stop for the night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read my previous answer, disregard it. The MooTools [`.bind`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Function#Function:bind) method supports passing parameters. So something else isn't working as you expect:

```
onclick: this._add.bind(this, 'y');
```

Here is a [simple setup on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/esave) to show how bind truly does pass parameters.

Comment: I'll try this.  Does not match the mootools docs, but...  (Those docs show the syntax as myFunction.bind([bind[, args[, evt]]]); which would imply this._add.bind(this,'x') ...would it not?  <update: tried this syntax, still no dice.>

Comment: @Dave ignore my first answer. Sorry I sent you in the wrong direction.

Comment: I posted the code after my original question (simplified to protect the innocent). It's not formatted correctly, seems to have lost the linefeeds...

Comment: so your JSBin thing proves I understand .bind -- must be the onClick or all the callbacks are messing me up somehow.

Answer (score 3):

this works and it keeps the scope within an element click event with the scope set to the class and not the element--there is no point in passing scope to the add method, it already has that:

```
var foo = new Class({
    Implements: [Options],
    add: function(what) {
        alert(what);
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.setOptions(options);

        this.options.element.addEvents({
            click: function() {
                this.add(this.options.what);
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
});

window.addEvent("domready", function() {
    new foo({
        element: $("foo"),
        what: "nothin'"
    });
});
```

just make an element with id=foo and click it to test (alerts nothin'). if your onclick is a function / event handler within your class as opposed to a normal element click event, then things are going to differ slightly - post a working skeleton of your work on http://mootools.net/shell/

Comment: thanks.  This seems to change the problem from the one I posted. I don't have the liberty of changing everything from the way it is already written. I just want to take two pieces of nearly identical code and change them to one with a parameter to guide their differences.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: erm - odd then, because your original solution works for me: http://mootools.net/shell/zD7Hz/

Answer (score 0):

The **only** purpose of bind is to "tell" the JS what object you mean when you say `this`. i.e. you pass as a parameter to `bind` an instance of the object you wish the `this` key word will refer to inside the function you used the `bind` on.

Comment: It's possible I have misunderstood the mootools docs on .bind -- but are you saying that I cannot send an argument to a bound function as I am trying to do here?  Seems unlikely....and I hope not true. You sound more expert than I, but this is specifically a mootools .bind and not just a bind - thanks

Comment: No, you understood the docs fine. @Itay your answer is incorrect per the MooTools docs: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Function#Function:bind

Comment: @Doug Neiner As far as events go, I believe I am correct. If you can get a code example that shows otherwise, then we have both gained new knowledge.